# Proving that A$^T$Ax = A$^T$b has a solution with certain assumptions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve a problem from my textbook.

Assumptions from previous problem:

> $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of unspecified rank, $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p =\inf\{\|Ax-b\|: x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$.
>
> The norm is abitrary on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now the problem is to show that, given the above assumptions, A$^T$Ax = A$^T$b has a solution.

My attempt (and shortcomings):
Given that $p =\inf\{\|Ax-b\|: x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ is attained for an abitrary norm, then we must also have specifically that $q =\inf\{\|Ax-b\|_2: x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ is attained.

This is the least-squares solution and by that we have $A^*$Ax=A$^*$b.

Obviously, if all of matrix A's elements are real (which I do not know whether they are), then $A^*$=$A^T$.

But my shortcoming is that, in the case of A having complex elements, I'm not sure how to proceed or if this is even the best method to prove that a solution actually exists.

Would appreciate some hints or a smoother approach.

Comment: It is rare that anyone will use $A^T$ as opposed to $A^*$ if complex entries are a possibility, least of all where norms are involved.  It is yet more suspicious that all definitions mention $\Bbb R^n$ as opposed to $\Bbb C^n$.  Are you **sure** that $A$ isn't assumed to have real entries?

Comment: Notably, if $x$ is allowed to have complex entries, $\|x\|^2 = x^Tx$ no longer defines a norm, and that throws a huge wrench into the whole idea of a "least squares" problem.

Comment: Ah... I think you may be right, might just be me messing up here. The book doesnt state specifically whether A is real-valued or not, but it does mention that the norm is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n\}$. And like you say, if the norm is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n\}$, then A couldn't possibly have complex elements right?

Comment: The norm must be Euclidean if you want to end up with the normal equations.